# brew upgrade cmake but the old version is still called

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

I am using MacOS High Sierra. I used `brew` to upgrade my `cmake` using the following command:

```
brew reinstall cmake
```

and it outputs as follows:

```
==> Reinstalling make 
==> Downloading https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles/bottles/cm
Already downloaded: /Users/johann/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/51a1df944e29ccc6fc3ac4dc1bd54832f3cadf8d8627a3571b70c1e497464cf1--cmake-3.17.0_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring cmake-3.17.0_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Emacs Lisp files have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.0_1: 6,156 files, 60.4MB
```

it seems fine and I test `cmake --version`, the output is still correct

```
cmake version 3.17.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

**However, when I use make to build a project** (ignore the irrelevant details):

```
cmake --build . --target mpc
```

I receive an extremely confusing feedback, showing that it is somehow still calling the older version, and the files of the older versions have already been removed by `brew`.

```
make: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.4/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Could anyone please tell me what is happening and how can I make my new version `cmake` work actually?

Comment: You can try: https://superuser.com/questions/975701/how-can-i-remove-outdated-installed-versions-of-homebrew-packages

Comment: Thank you for answering tigertang >_<. However, it does not work, as my brew clean nothing about cmake, and under /usr/local/Cellar/cmake there is only one version 3.17.0_1. It seems that the version 3.11.4 is attached to some configure file.

Comment: You may need to delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file from the build directory and reconfigure your project.

Comment: Thank you vre! It is the exact problem that I encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved!

I was using `cmake` under a /build directory and this directory has already had some `cmake cache`, after I clean the folder and do configure again, there is no error anymore.

Thanks everyone for comment!